# UITableViewのアコーディオン機能を特定のセクションでのみ停止させる方法

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, uitableview

iPhoneアプリを製作中です。下記リンク先のサンプル（UITableViewにアコーディオン機能を
追加する）についてですが、特定のセクションでのみアコーディオン機能を停止させるには
どうすればいいのでしょうか？
[iOSでセクションタップ方式のアコーディオン型TableViewライブラリを作ってみた。](http://jtaka1012.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/16/075734)
以上、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ざっと見ただけですが、リンク先のライブラリだと外からの開閉制御は想定していないように思います。
なので、

ライブラリ内に手を加える（MITライセンスなので問題は無いと思います）
 or
ライブラリを参考に自作する

になるのではないでしょうか。

個人的には自作した方が良いように思いますが、ライブラリ内に手を加えるのであれば、`SGLAccordionTableView.m`の`touchesEnded`が主な対象になると思います。

```
// タッチが終了した時の処理
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ～中略～

    ↓この辺とか
    // アコーディオンの開閉を実施
    if(isExpanded){
        [self expandSection:section rowCount:count];
    }else{
        [self collapseSection:section rowCount:count];
    }

    ～中略～
}
```

リンク先に

**プルリクエストお待ちしております**
・コードによる開閉操作

と書いてあるので、作成者さんにプルリクエストしてみるのも面白いんじゃないでしょうか。